# Mongodb - updating a collection with >100,000 documents in migration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

Following migration code seems to be getting stuck while updating this huge collection.

```
@ChangeSet(order = "010", id = "add_tenant_to_product", author = "pn")
fun addTenantToProduct(mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate) {
    log.info("Adding tenants to products")
    val query = Query()
    val update = Update()
    update.set("tenants", arrayOf("shared"))

    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Product::class.java)
}

@ChangeSet(order = "011", id = "add_tenant_to_product_version", author = "pn")
fun addTenantToProductVersion(mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate) {
    log.info("Adding tenants to product-version")
    val query = Query()
    val update = Update()
    ...
```

The last few lines of the application log indicate the changeset getting invoked but subsequent one not getting invoked.

> ```
> 2021-05-11 08:00:29.385  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.a.a.mongock.changelog.Migration        : Adding tenants to products
> 2021-05-11 08:00:29.576  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection
> ```

The Spring actuator health probe fails because of this and the container keeps on restarting. Is there a better API to use which will be faster?

Note:

1. version used: 'com.github.cloudyrock:mongock:1.12'
2. below is the configuration

```kotlin
@Profile("!tenant")
@Configuration
class MongockConfig : AbstractMongoConfiguration() {

    @Value("\${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private lateinit var uri: String

    @Value("\${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private lateinit var database: String

    override fun mongoClient(): MongoClient {
        return MongoClient(MongoClientURI(uri))
    }

    override fun getDatabaseName(): String {
        return database
    }

    @Bean
    fun mongock(): Mongock {
        return MongockBuilder(mongoClient(), databaseName, "com.somepackage.mongock.changelog")
            .setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate())
            .setLockQuickConfig()
            .build()
    }
}
```

Here are the logs

---

> ```
> 2021-05-10 10:59:33.406  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:16, serverValue:26359638}] to dummy-clusterr-39649.servers.mongodirector.com:27017
> 2021-05-10 10:59:33.525  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.github.cloudyrock.mongock.LockChecker  : Mongbee trying to acquire the lock
> 2021-05-10 10:59:33.574  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.github.cloudyrock.mongock.LockChecker  : Lock is taken by other process until: Mon May 10 11:01:03 GMT 2021
> 2021-05-10 10:59:33.574  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.github.cloudyrock.mongock.LockChecker  : Mongock is going to sleep to wait for the lock:  90265 ms(1 minutes)
> 2021-05-10 11:01:03.839  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.github.cloudyrock.mongock.LockChecker  : Mongbee trying to acquire the lock
> 2021-05-10 11:01:03.844  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.github.cloudyrock.mongock.LockChecker  : Mongbee acquired the lock until: Mon May 10 11:04:03 GMT 2021
> 2021-05-10 11:01:03.844  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : Mongock starting the data migration sequence..
> 2021-05-10 11:01:03.982  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : Reflections took 60 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 2 keys and 3 values 
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.038  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@7abd0e71 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.046  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@6635f36 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.047  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@61352a80 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.052  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@7576ed14 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.054  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@b0302179 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.068  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@e6caade0 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.071  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@2688129a pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.073  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@e46af677 pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.075  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.Mongock    : com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.ChangeEntry@d788b92f pass over
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.077  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.a.a.mongock.changelog.Migration        : Adding organisations to questions
> 2021-05-10 11:01:04.158  INFO [product-service,,,] 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:17, serverValue:26359725}] to dummy-clusterr-39649.servers.mongodirector.com:27017
> ```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a bit more information, such as mongock version you are using, log trace(what you show is not enough fo diagnostic), mongock configuration, etc?

On the other hand, you should use `MongockTemplate` instead `MongoTemplate` directly. It's the same API, you wont miss anything. Actually using a MongoTemplate directly should throw an exception.

For more information, please check [Mongock's documenation](https://www.mongock.io/spring-profiles#mongocktemplate)

Comment: Added some more details.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong in the log. But it's weird that the connection is re-opened again. Are you sure it's not related to MongoDB itself or spring.

On the other hand, you are using a very old version. Last one is 4.3.8 and ewe are working on version 5 to provide very cool features.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong since I am new to Mongodb. The migration works fine on my local machine which has few records. So I suspect it's a large number of records when deployed on the testing environment.

Comment: I suggest you to check your MongoDB log, as that's doesn't show much. Just the fact that is connecting again, which is weird.